# How can we pass all items in a list from model class repository to controller and then to view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, asp.net-core

I need to pass all elements from a list to view through controller. The list was created and it is coded in Model class. I had used findAll but it doesn't work. 
I don't need any particular condition to satisfy!
here is my list

```
Rq = new List<Customers>()
{
    new Customers{Id=2, Fname="Thomas", Lname="shelby", Location="Canada",Contact=9874561230,Email="thomas@gmail.com",Password="143",Category="developer",Status="pending"},
    new Customers{Id=3, Fname="markuz", Lname="shelby", Location="Britan",Contact=9874561239,Email="mark@gmail.com",Password="13",Category="user",Status="approved"},
    new Customers{Id=1, Fname="James", Lname="M", Location="Kottayam", Contact=9685748596, Email="james@gmail.com", Password="123", Category="admin", Status="approved" },
};
```

I had used this function

```
public Customers Addap(Customers customers)
{
    return Rq.FindAll(p => p.Id > 1);
}
```

Addap is my action in home controller.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddapAsync()
{
    ViewBag.oid = oid;
    HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44397/api/Values/Addap");
    if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Customers user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customers>(await Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        ViewBag.Customers = user;
        return View(user);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
    }
}
```

my api controller is

```
[HttpGet("Addap")]
public IActionResult Addap(Customers customers)
{
    cust = new Customers();
    cust = _customerRepo.Addap(customers);
    if (cust != null)
    {
        return Ok(cust);
    }
    else
    {
        return (null);
    }
}
```

view i have used

```
@{Customer.Models.Customers cust = ViewBag.Customers;
    int id = ViewBag.oid;
}
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form asp-controller="Home">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        FNAME
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        LNAME
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        LOCATION
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        CONTACT
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        EMAIL
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        PASSWORD
                    </th>

                    <th>
                        CATEGORY
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        STATUS
                    </th>

                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model) {
                <tr>

                    <td>@cust.Id</td>
                    <td>@cust.Fname</td>
                    <td>@cust.Lname</td>
                    <td>@cust.Location</td>
                    <td>@cust.Contact</td>
                    <td>@cust.Email</td>
                    <td>**********</td>
                    <td>@cust.Category</td>
                    <td>@cust.Status</td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" Approve ", "Home ", new { cust.Id})'">Details</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="">Activity Log</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                }
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action(" Details ", "Home ", new { id})'">Back</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When you want to return all, your Method `Addap` has the wrong return type. It only returns one Item. So you have to change this to `List<Customers>` or another collection type. Then you are able to return the list directly.

Comment: Also note that if your `Customers` class holds the info of **one** customer, it should be named `Customer` (singular)

Comment: what is your `model` in view ?!

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi my model name is Customers.

Comment: @Ananthakrishna Show us your `Controller` code. If you want to return your list to your `View`, you can use `ViewBag`: `ViewBag.mylist=Rq;`. Also what does this line return : `return Rq.FindAll(p => p.Id > i);`. I feel it should be: `return Rq.FindAll(p => p.Id > customers.Id);`

Comment: I know. I Mean in your view you have `@model Customers` or `@model IEnumerable<Customers>`?

Comment: @HamedMoghadasi I have used ```@{Customer.Models.Customers cust = ViewBag.Customers;```

Comment: @RahulSharma 
my api controller code below
``` [HttpGet("Addap")]
        public IActionResult Addap(Customers customers)
        {
            cust = new Customers();
            cust = _customerRepo.Addap(customers);
            if (cust != null)
            {
                return Ok(cust);
            }
            else
            {
                return (null);
            }
        }

Comment: you didn't get my point. please add your `View` and your `Model` to question.

Comment: @Ananthakrishna Please update your question with the `Controller` code. It is very difficult to read the code in the comments.

Comment: okay,  i have updated my question sorry for the inconvenince.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so you need to return a `List` of customers instead of only one customer therefore in your API method, make an instance of `List<Customers>`:

```
[HttpGet("Addap")]
public IActionResult Addap(Customers customers)
{
  List<Customers> cust = new List<Customers>();
  cust = _customerRepo.Addap(customers);
  if (cust != null)
  {
    return Ok(cust);
  }
  else
  {
    return (null);
  }
}
```

Also your `Addap` should return a `List<Customers>`. I also observed that you are sending a Customer object to this method but is that actually required? Maybe you wanted to do something like:

```
public List<Customers> Addap(Customers customers)
{
    return Rq.FindAll(p => p.Id > 1);
    //return Rq.FindAll(p => p.Id == customers.Id);
}
```

Now once you are returning the data that you need via your `API`, you can de-serialize the above response as:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddapAsync()
{
  ViewBag.oid = oid;
  HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44397/api/Values/Addap");
  if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    List<Customers> user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customers>>(await Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    ViewBag.Customers = user;
    return View(user);
  }
  else
  {
     return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
  }
}
```

And finally in your `View`, you can loop over this `ViewBag` as:

```
@foreach(var customer in ViewBag.Customers)
{            
  <tr>    
  <td>@customer.Fname</td>
  <td>@customer.LName</td>
  <!-- So On -->
  </tr>        
}
```

Comment: @Ananthakrishna What values do you get here: `cust = _customerRepo.Addap(customers);`. It should return a `List<Customers>`

Comment: @Ananthakrishna So you need to design your method in a way that it should accept a parameter of type `Customer`. For testing purpose, you can send a predefined value

Comment: in cust it retruns all the records but. in html page it return an error RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Customer.Models.Customers>' to 'Customer.Models.Customers'

AspNetCore.Views_Home_Addap.ExecuteAsync() in Addap.cshtml
+
@{Customer.Models.Customers cust = ViewBag.Customers;

Comment: @Ananthakrishna Change this line: `@{Customer.Models.Customers cust = ViewBag.Customers;` to `@{List<Customer.Models.Customers> cust = ViewBag.Customers;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the full list `Rq`, you can create your method like this:

```
public List<Customers> Addap()
{
    return Rq;
}
```

Comment: hi,  it strike another error in my api controller
```
[HttpGet("Addap")]
        public IActionResult Addap(Customers customers)
        {
            cust = new Customers();
            cust = _customerRepo.Addap(customers);
            if (cust != null)
            {
                return Ok(cust);
            }
            else
            {
                return (null);
            }
        }
```
CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Customer.Models.Customers>' to 'Customer.Models.Customers'
@Presi